# Avoid having to enter password for updates of app on child's account

Tags: applications, password, ipados

When I update App Store apps on an iPad using my child's account, I'm each time asked to enter the password for the account. Is there anyway to avoid this? I don't see the reason why app updates would need to be put behind a password, even for child accounts.